# CSS dropdown submenu with dynamic width: how to align left?

Tags: html, css

It's easy to have a LI > UL submenu show up with CSS:

```
.menu ul { padding-left: 0px; }
.menu li { list-style-type: none; display: inline-block; padding-left: 0px; margin: 1px; background: #ddd; width: 100px; }
.menu li ul { display: none; }
.menu li:hover > ul { display: block; position: absolute; background: #000; }
.menu li:hover > ul li { display: block; background: #bbb; width: auto; }
```

In this case, the size of the submenu automatically adjusts to the width of the content. The submenu aligns left where the left of the parent LI element is.

Let's say I want to align the submenu to the right, so the right should lign up with the parent LI's right side. I can do that by having a fixed width of the submenu, and use this (assuming the parent LI is 100px wide):

```
#menu-left li:hover > ul { width: 150px; margin-left: -50px; }
```

But then you can't use flexible width submenu's anymore. Also, you need to know the width of the parent LI.

JS Fiddle explains my question best: https://jsfiddle.net/ybc0uxq8/1/

Anyone knows a way to have the right side of the sub UL lign up with the right side of the parent LI without needing a fixed submenu width, and allowing for a submenu width larger than the parent LI?

Comment: Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ybc0uxq8/1/)?

Comment: You've linked to my original JSfiddle I think... ;)

Comment: Try again [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ybc0uxq8/3/).

Comment: Thanks. You've came up with the same solution as @amessihel below. As I responded there as well, in my original fiddle, the submenu could be wider than the parent LI. Your solution works, but disables this possibility. Do you know a way without breaking this possibility?

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/ybc0uxq8/5/) is another try. It is what you want?

Comment: Wow, that seems to work! Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments/request, here is the edited version of the original `CSS` code to reflect the desired result:

```
/* apply to both */
.menu ul { padding-left: 0px; }
.menu li { list-style-type: none; display: inline-block; position: relative; padding-left: 0px; margin: 1px; background: #ddd; }
.menu li ul { display: none; }
.menu li:hover > ul { display: block; position: absolute; background: #000; right: 0; }
.menu li:hover > ul li { background: #bbb; white-space: nowrap; }
```

Answer (score 1):

A good way is to put `.menu li { position:relative;...}` so sub element will be placed *relatively* to parent when their `position` attribute is set to `absolute`. Then remove the `width` attribute from `#menu-left li:hover > ul` selector and add `right:0` into it.

Update. To have subentries larger than their parents (as requested in the comments), set the properties of .menu li ul selector like this :

```
.menu li ul { display: none; min-width:150px; }
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ybc0uxq8/6//) here (updated).

Comment: Interesting, thanks. But is it possible this way to have the submenu width larger than the parent LI width?

Comment: What do you mean by a "larger" width ? Moreover, isn'it another point ?

Comment: What I mean, in my original fiddle, the submenu could be wider than the parent LI. Your solution works, but disables this possibility :-).

Comment: Ok, so you want a flexible width with minimal value ? Updated anwser.